# unwanted margin on the left side of every pages

Tags: jquery, html, css, user-interface

if check `http://tadris3.ir/` , you'll see there is a weird space in the left side of all pages,

 could anyone help me out to fix this annoying problem ?

[image]

Comment: Nobody can / will help unless you provide the relevant markup / CSS.  You can *not* link to the site with the problem, because as soon as the site goes down (or is fixed), this question has zero value.

Comment: i don't know where this problem comes and i can't copy the whole site here ? what shoud i do ?

Comment: The first step to understanding your problem is to use your browser console.  Right click on the space in question, click "Inspect Element", and learn to use the tool - it will show you the element(s), the style(s) being applied, and quickly you can / will see what as causing that margin.

Comment: Additionally - there's no space when I view it.  Which browser / OS are you using?

Comment: i know how to use browser console and how to check margins ! but it cant help me !

Comment: chrome and mac OSX

Comment: It's not showing on Chrome / Mac OSX for me.

Comment: I get flickering to left and right when scrolling through the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure without looking at any code but be sure to use some sort of CSS rest. All browsers ship with some of their own CSS preset for things like body, html, label, all the h tags. I like starting from a blank slate. Here is one of the most commonly used one by one of the first people to recommend them; Eric Meyer. 
[CSS resets](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing your code, just having a guess: Try using font-size:0 for the page where you are getting unwanted margin and then set appropriate font-size value for the children elements.